# Bigquery: how to stream streaming logs?

Tags: google-bigquery

Are there any best practises to log streaming logs into Bigquery? So that:
(1), it wouldn't slow down data streaming itself
(2), automatic alert can be sent when exceptional frequent errors happen or when certain errors happen
(3), easy to get error/requests ratio stat. 
Or, I can accomplish the above goals w/o bigquery? ( we are doing 24*7 continuous streaming so that the logs are supposed to continuously grow w/o up limit)

Comment: check this post from Shine: http://blog.shinetech.com/2014/08/25/put-on-your-streaming-shoes/